# not able to install numpy package

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, package, pip

This is a very basic question but I am not able to find solution to it. I am new to python and I want to install packages numpy,pylab ,etc.I am able to install **httpie** by

```
 pip install httpie ,
```

but for numpy its throwing error:

```
Requirement already satisfied<use --upgrade to upgrade>**
```

Does this mean that numpy is already installed and if yes then why am I not able to run in IDLE

The following error is being shown when I wrote

```
>>> import numpy as gt

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
  import numpy as gt
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 153, in <module>
  from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
  from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
  from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
  import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
   from . import multiarray
  ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Also when i tried to install pylab i am getting the error with

```
pip install pylab
```

I am getting

```
Downloading unpacking data
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pylab
```

I have tried easy_install to but getting:

```
easy_install numpy
```

It's showing:

```
Searching for numpy
Best match:numpy 1.8.0
Adding numpy to easy_install .pth file

Using c:\python27\lib\site-packages
Processing dependencies for numpy
Finished processing dependencies for numpy
```

This too isn't working, but in IDLE same error is shown.

Comment: Have you considered some custom Python distributions such as Enthought Canopy, Continuum Anaconda, PythonXY, or WinPython?

Comment: no ,i am just a starter

Comment: If that is the case, you may better off with one of the python distributions @richizy suggested.

Comment: @richizy:Hey thanks, using the among the ones you mentioned